# Piping output from two tar processes into a single child

Tags: linux, shell, tar, piping

I can pipe two commands into a single child like so (Edit: actually you can't do it like this, see sarnold answers):

```
(echo "1.1 2.2 3.3") && (echo "4.4 5.5 6.6") | cat
```

which outputs

```
1.1 2.2 3.3
4.4 5.5 6.6
```

I want to do something similar with the output of tar.  Currently I'm analysing data stored in a single tar files like so:

```
tar -x --to-command MySerialiser -f MyData1.tar.xz | MyAnalyser
```

where `MySerialiser` preprocesses the data in a form ready for `MyAnalyser` to read.

I now want to pipe the output of two tar files to `MyAnalyser`.

I tried the following but output arrives on the terminal.

```
(tar -x --to-command MySerialiser -f MyData1.tar.xz) && (tar -x --to-command MySerialiser -f MyData2.tar.xz)  | MyAnalyser
```

Can I do this with shell?  or do I need to repackage my tar files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it wrong (even for the first snippet).

```
{ tar -x --to-command MySerialiser -f MyData1.tar.xz && tar -x --to-command MySerialiser -f MyData2.tar.xz ; }  | MyAnalyser
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your `echo` example shows what you think it shows; try replacing `|cat` with `>/dev/null`:

```
$ (echo "1.1 2.2 3.3") && (echo "4.4 5.5 6.6") > /dev/null
1.1 2.2 3.3
```

The output from the first `echo` is going straight to the terminal (which isn't yet redirected), and the output from the second `echo` is going through the pipeline (upon the successful execution of the first `echo` command).

I don't think this kind of construction will ever lead to what you want -- so what is your *goal* in handling the outputs from two `tar` commands into one program at once?